# POST parameters not available on 1 specific page

Tags: php, iphone, post, httprequest

The strangest thing is happening here. I'm trying to do a POST request from an iPhone application, and the PHP page that it needs to call does never receive the POST parameters. When I change the page it is posting to, same directory, different name, it all comes through without a problem.

I'm testing the parameters with:

```
print_r($_POST);
```

Anybody any idea what could be going on here?

EDIT:
The request is done using HTTPTask, the URL is 100% correct because I get other echo's that I set for testing returned and I access the $_POST using normal $_POST['key']. The $_POST request is empty when I post to file.php, no problem when i post to file1.php.

```
var params = [] //array filled with stuff
var req = HTTPTask()

    req.POST("http://url/file.php", parameters: params, success: { (response: HTTPResponse) -> Void in
        var data = response.responseObject as NSData
        var str = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        println(str)
        }) { (error: NSError) -> Void in
            println("Error returned")
    }
```

Regards,

Ron

Comment: check your posting url is correct?

Comment: how do you take the value of the variable that you have send with POST? like this? $variabile = $_POST['nameoftheinput'];

Comment: can you post your posting code also?

Comment: Edited with additional info

Comment: Can you include what the form looks like that you're submitting too?

Comment: Do you have a .htaccess or redirecting rules in your vhost configuration?

Comment: I checked all .htaccess files on the server and there doesn't seem to be anything off with them.... No redirect going on.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what do you know... I deleted the .htaccess files and re-created them. Afterwards I reset the iOS simulator and now it works.... Several hours of my life wasted away!

Thanks for the help everyone.